# I cannot set the root of the tree to null?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I was trying to solve this problem on leetcode, by seeing what i have written i think my logic is correct but i am getting the same tree in return as output which is wrong. I had a doubt can i not set the current scope of root of tree to null ? after seeing the solutions of people they have made the root.left null or root.right null not the root itself like mine.
Am i missing some basic concept here.
Link to the LeetCode problem :- https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-pruning/
My solution :-

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public TreeNode pruneTree(TreeNode root) {
        cleanTree(root);
        return root;
    }
    
    public boolean cleanTree(TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null) {
            return true;
        }
        boolean left = cleanTree(root.left);
        boolean right = cleanTree(root.right);
        if(root.val == 0 && left  && right) {
            root = null;
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I had a doubt can i not set the root of tree to null"* Since you're not asked to do that, why is that a concern? The assignment is to "return the same tree where every **subtree** (of the given tree) not containing a 1 has been removed". Since you're only removing sub-trees, the **root node will always remain**.

Comment: The fact that you named the `cleanTree()` parameter **`root`** is confusing, because most of the time, the value isn't the root of the tree. The parameter to `pruneTree()` is "the root of the tree". The parameter to `cleanTree()` is just some node. --- You should never null out the node itself, you null out the `left` and `right` references, then return `true` if you want the *caller* to null out the reference to the node.

Comment: So you are asking why `root = null` doesn't null out the `root.left` or `root.right` in the caller. The answer is here: [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/5221149).

Comment: @Andreas Thanks you now I got clearly understooded where i had been wrong. You exactly cleared what i had doubt in the how the things are passed

Answer (score 0):

They set `root.left` or `root.right` to null because they can't set the current node `root` to null.

Setting `root` to null as you did inside the if statement only sets the memory address of root to null within the scope of the current method. The `pruneTree` method would not see `root` becoming null.

Side note, the root node is not guaranteed to be non-null.
e.g. with the tree

```
 0 <--root
0 0
```

, the root would be null

Comment: Since the assignment is to "return the same tree where every **subtree** (of the given tree) not containing a 1 has been removed". Only the subtrees are nulled out, the root always remains and will never be set to null. Second half of answer is wrong.

Comment: This question is definitely vague, but I coded this exact problem yesterday with the assumption that a tree of all zeros has root null, and it worked on every test case, not to mention that the solution on the lc website did the same thing as I

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in java variables passed to a method will never be assigned to by the method itself. *This was introduced to prevent evil calls unexpectedly modifying passed variables. [Code Quality]*

Hence setting a variable involves assigning the call's return value to the variable.

```
public TreeNode pruneTree(TreeNode root) {
    root = cleanTree(root);
    return root;
}

public TreeNode cleanTree(TreeNode node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return node;
    }
    node.left = cleanTree(root.left);
    node.right = cleanTree(root.right);
    if (node.val == 0) {
        if (node.left == null) {
            return node.right;
        }
        if (node.right == null) {
            return node.left;
        }
        // Bad luck ... should delete node.
    }
    return node;
}
```

Here the boolean result is not needed. In the simplest case the passed TreeNode is returned.

(For clarity I wrote `root = cleanTree(root);`.)

---

***Deleting a node in the middle***

```
public TreeNode cleanTree(TreeNode node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return node;
    }
    node.left = cleanTree(root.left);
    node.right = cleanTree(root.right);
    if (node.val == 0) {
        if (node.left == null) {
            return node.right;
        }
        if (node.right == null) {
            return node.left;
        }
```

The if's above now are just a heuristic optimisation,
doing often less work.

```
        // Delete node in the middle:
        // - either node.left as node.right's left-most leaf's left,
        // - or node.right as node.left's right-most leaf's right.
        // Sometimes called a pointer rotation (for 3 positions).
        if (depth(node.left) < depth(node.right) {
            TreeNode rightMin = node.right;
            while (rightMin.left != null) {
                rightMin = rightMin.left;
            }
            rightMin.left = node.left;
            return node.right;
        } else {
            TreeNode leftMax = node.left;
            while (leftMax.left != null) {
                leftMax = leftMax.right;
            }
            leftMax.right = node.right;
            return node.left;
        }            
    }
    return node;
}

private int depth(TreeNode node) {
    return node == null ? 0
             : 1 + Math.max(depth(node.left), depth(node.right);
}
```